# Differences between adding a project as dependency and as a plugin

Tags: grails, gradle

When modularizing a grails application, when does it make sense to add the module as a plugin vs gradle dependency?

For Example:

1. *akaDomain*  contains all the domain objects.
2. *akaWebsites* contains all the presentation logic.
3. *akaService1* contains some services.
4. *akaService2* contains some other services.

All the websites and services share *akaDomain*.

Can the domain classes present in *akaDomain* be used for scaffolding controllers and views in another application like *akaService* and *akaWebsite*?

Can this be achieved using plugins or dependency or both.
Please explain what am I missing if I don't make a plugin of *akaDomain*.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811453/modularize-grails-application-grails-2-3-x.) uses plugin to explain how to modularize grails app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use the domains defined in one plugin as the basis for scaffolding in another plugin or in a main application. There are several practical considerations when doing so however:

- If you choose to implement UI in a plugin, then you are committing to a UI look and feel that is to be shared across multiple applications. This is often very difficult when doing custom / contract development where every customer wants their own personal look and feel. You will want to think about selecting a UI abstraction as well that allows flexibility on theme support at least. We use Twitter Bootstrap for this purpose but there are several others that fit the bill.
- You must manage the dependencies between the "domain/service" and the "UI" plugins. This is true of any plugin ecosystem, but once you commit to abstraction, this discipline is very important or you end up with dependency dead ends or cycles. It is a lot of work, but the pay off for productivity is very high.

As for the question on Grails Plugins vs Gradle dependencies:

Plugins are in fact Gradle dependencies (in Grails 3.x at least). That is, plugin dependency management is implemented on top of Gradle. Plugins provide additional support for integrating into a Grails application that include things like:

- Automated spring bean registration and initialization at startup.
- Participation in application component reloading.
- Artefact definitions and initialization at startup.

So, implement using plugins and you get the best of both worlds.